# How can i json.loads("""") 4 nails?

Tags: javascript, python, json

i can't send double nail on my form .
Javascript sending variable:

```
job = '{"sender": "omgbbqhax”,"message" : "'+variable+'" }';
```

Python code:

```
import json
mad = json.loads(job)
print mad[‘sender’]
print mad[‘message’]
```

But if write

```
variable = """";
job = '{"sender": "omgbbqhax”,"message" : "'+variable+'" }';
```

i have a error ? how can i make ?

Comment: You have curly quotes in there. That's a problem.

Comment: I'm confused: what is a "double nail"?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Presumably a double-quote character, `"`.

Answer (score 5):

Invalid quotes:

```
job = '{"sender": "omgbbqhax”,"message" : "'+variable+'" }';
                            ^---- curly quote
```

You should NOT be building your own JSON string anyways. One JS-metacharacter in your inserted data and you've introduced a syntax error that will kill the entire JS string. You should build a NATIVE data structure and then encode that to json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get literal double quotes into your string and still use double quotes on the outside you'll have to escape the inner pair:

```
variable = "\"\""
```

You could always switch your outer quotes to single ones too:

```
variable = '""'
```

Comment: i cant use your example because this is chat script and i cant intervention this variable.